# pyQT equivalent to VB-6 PSet

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a program I wrote in VB-6 to emulate an old Timex 2068 Z80 micro.

The display is a direct memory write in a specific area of memory and in VB I look for that range and them use VB-6's PSet to set the pixel(s) in question.

I have been trying to understand the example below..

What I am not understanding is how QPainter interacts and how to call drawpoints() from outside the class with x,y and pen color arguments.

Everything I have tried ends up with a QPainter is not active error...

Any assistance would be appreciated as I've spent hours trying this that and the other thing, to no avail.

Thanks

```
import sys, random
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Points')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawPoints(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawPoints(self, qp):

        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
        size = self.size()

        for i in range(1000):
            x = random.randint(1, size.width()-1)
            y = random.randint(1, size.height()-1)
            qp.drawPoint(x, y)     


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This seems to run fine, what is the problem with this?

Comment: Yes, the code as written runs. However, I need something that will allow me to continue to use the code after the fact to emulate VB-6's PSet(x, y) command. I have not been able to figure how to restructure the code to allow me to 'drawpoint(x, y)' from outside the class. In short thanks for reading my post. I need something that will allow me to update the 'display' throughout the run of the program.